# Maven 3.2.2 packagingExcludes

Tags: regex, maven, ant

I want to exclude multiple regex expressions using the packagingExcludes element of my pom.xml. According to the Maven documentation, this element contains "a comma-separated list of Ant file set patterns".

However, from what I can tell each of these is evaluated as an "OR" to the others. That is if I want to do this:

```
<packagingExcludes>
    %regex[WEB-INF/lib(?!abc).jar],
    %regex[WEB-INF/lib(?!xyz).jar]
</packagingExcludes>
```

nothing gets included. abc.jar is excluded because it is not xyz.jar and xyz.jar gets excluded because it is not abc.jar.

Is there a way to get Maven to evaluate these using an "AND" relationship?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you wish to exclude all files from `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` *except* for `abc.jar` and `xyz.jar`.

You can solve this by providing a single regular expression that matches those exclusions. Everything in `WEB-INF/lib/`, except for those things that then contain `(abc|xyz).jar` and then end, and which goes on to end in `.jar`.

```
%regex[WEB-INF/lib/(?!(abc|xyz).jar$).*.jar]
```

For maintainability, you may wish to consider listing the exclusions instead.